# I want to know the principle of 'pandas ewm'

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I want to know the principle of 'pandas ewm'. I know the formula for ewm, but I want to know how the 'alpha' is specified and how it is calculated. The results of the code below are x:[1,2,3,4,5]- ewm -> [1, 1.75, 2.615385, 3.55, 4.520661]. Tell me how the ewm value when x is 3, 4, and 5 can lead to that result. thank you

-test['y']: use the ewm function

```
test= pd.DataFrame({'x':[0,1,2,3,4,5]})
test['y']=test['x'].ewm(span=2).mean()
```

Comment: You can provide your own `alpha`.  I'm a bit unsure of what you are asking.  `alpha` defaults to `None` if not provided.  Please review [ask] and create a [mcve]

Comment: What would you expect the result to be, and how is that different from the actual result? According to [the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ewm.html) you didn't provide an alpha, so none is used

Comment: @G.Anderson that's a little misleading, since there's an equivalence between `span` and `alpha`, something like `alpha = 2/(1+span)`

Comment: @Yuca, you're correct, that was a typo. It should read `None` is used, as in the value passed into the function is the default of `None`. Thank you for the correction.